# Five types of order vs Five types of orders?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am a bit confused by the use of plurals.

Let's say in this situation, when I am telling a person that there are five types of 'order method' for purchasing Product A, should I say "five types of **order**" or "five types of **orders**"?

Comment: There are five ordering methods, or there are five ways of placing an order.

Comment: There are five *order types*: telephone, internet, email,  snail mail...

Comment: ... plus one secret order type?

Comment: @RoaringFish- yeah, I couldn’t think of a reasonable fifth type (although I didn’t try very hard because I was headed off to bed) thus the ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to think about here is what it is that there are five of. If you look at a sentence like *five cans of paint* for example, there are five cans. Not five 'paints'. In *five colours of car* there are five colours, not five cars - you can have one car in a choice of five colours.

In your sentence, are there five types of order, or did you receive five orders? If the *five* is telling us how many types of order, then you would say *five types of order*.

Answer (score 0):

***Five types of order*** would be technically correct but very, very awkward. A better way of stating it would be:

> There are five ways of ordering it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as it first looks. Consider the following:

> 1. There are five types of car(s). ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types%20of%20car%2C%20types%20of%20cars&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20cars%3B%2Cc0))
> 2. There are two types of paint(s). (Ricky's example; [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types%20of%20paint%2Ctypes%20of%20paints&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20paint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20paints%3B%2Cc0))
> 3. There are three types of person/people. ([some other example](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/526385-there-are-three-types-of-people-in-this-world-firstly); [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types%20of%20person%2Ctypes%20of%20people&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20people%3B%2Cc0))

According to Ngram, the plural is more common for *cars* and *people*, and the singular for *paint*.

I suspect there is something going on with different levels of formality or intrinsic vs imposed qualities when using the *X of Y* construct, but it may simply come down to familiarity. If the plural is more familiar (example 3), the singular form may sound more serious: *there are two types of person*. If the singular is more familiar (example 2), the plural then sounds more intriguing: *there are two types of paints*.

In your case, the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types%20of%20order%2Ctypes%20of%20orders&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20orders%3B%2Cc0) for *types of order/s* shows that the singular was more popular for most of the 1900s, but that both are now used about as often as each other.

My *opinion* is that you should use *five types of order* (singular) if you are expounding on the philosophy of The Order. The plural form *five types of orders* sounds clunky even for a casual listing of variants for data processing, and I would recommend rephrasing. E.g. "there are five ways to order something".